# files made with Gedit cannot be found/made executable from terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit, ruby, html

I recently (as in within the hour) made one .rb file and one .html file. When I enter them into my Terminal they always return: "No Such File or Directory". It does not matter if the manner of input is as `chmod +x rubyfile` or `./htmlfile` not even `find rubyfile`works. I have looked for posted solutions but it seems everyone with this issue has been running a 32bit.exe file on a 64bit version of ubuntu. But I do not believe that to be the case being that I made these files in the TextEditor that comes with Ubuntu: "Gedit".

Comment: `find rubyfile` probably doesn't mean what you think it does: try `find ~ -iname 'rubyfile'`

Comment: Please try opening a terminal window, `cd` to the directory containing your files, and then run `ls -a`. Do you see your files listed in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Gedit ( at least on Ubuntu 16.04 ) has list of recent files in `File` menu

[image]

If you can open those files and click on `Save as` submenu you will be presented with File Selection dialog, which will allow you to figure out which directory and where those files are located.

As for the `find` command, [steeldriver properly pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894749/files-made-with-gedit-cannot-be-found-made-executable-from-terminal#comment1400641_894749)  that you need to specify proper format:

```
find <directory> -iname "filename"
```

I would recommend you do the following. Let's say you have for example file called `myruby.rb`. Then you should be able to just run `find` "$HOME" -type f -iname "myruby.rb"`, but you can also just search for any file with`.rb`extension like so:`find "$HOME" -type f -iname "*.rb". Note that adding `-type f` will allow you to look only for files and ignore other types (such as directories and symlinks).